# connectionstring: object reference not set to an object instance

Tags: c#, database

I want to connect with a db with a `connectionstring` in an application config file but always get this error :

> object reference not set to an object instance

In the first code line with the `ConfigurationManger` I have checked it several times but I do not think that I have made a mistake. Hope you can find something.

**Code**

```
string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnect"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select* From dsds m with (nolock) inner join asdas a with (nolock) on a.id = m.id where  test....., conn);
                ds = new DataTable(" ");
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="dbConnect"
     connectionString="Data Source=test;Initial Catalog=as;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string con = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnect"].ConnectionString;
```

Edit:

As you have two app.config, you can either delete one, or if you want to control programatically which app.config to use,  Refer [How can I use several Application Configuration Files in one project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557437/how-can-i-use-several-application-configuration-files-in-one-project)

Comment: Have you referenced the System.Configuration dll in your project?

Comment: Do you have multiple app.config files?

Comment: yes i have otherwise i would not have get this error

Comment: Sorry. I could not get for which question it was Yes.

Comment: Can you please verify if System.Configuration is present in the References folder of your project?

Comment: Does both the app config files contain the connection string?